# React component inside function map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I have a question about react component. What I want to do is render a component inside the map function and pass the component inside the map function the object returned in each iteration.

The code above works fine for me.

```
export class MapContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const style = {
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Map 
                google={this.props.google}
                style={this.style}
                initialCenter={{lat: 35.85472104, lng: 14.48779873}}
                zoom={11}>

                <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick} name={'Current location'} />
            </Map>
        );
    }
}
```

But as I said before I want to put the component Marker inside a the map function but it doesn't works properly:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';

export class MapContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const style = {
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
        }

        const objMarkers = [
            {
                title: "The marker`s title will appear as a tooltip.",
                name: "Soma",
                position: [35.85472104, "14.48779873"]
            },
            {
                title: "The marker`s title will appear as a tooltip.",
                name: "Soma",
                position: ["35.9220325", "14.37038234"]
            }
        ]
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Map 
                google={this.props.google}
                style={this.style}
                initialCenter={{lat: 35.85472104, lng: 14.48779873}}
                zoom={11}>

                return this.objMarkers.map((marker) => 
                    <Marker title={marker.title} name={marker.name} />
                );
            </Map>
        );
    }
}

const LoadingContainer = (props) => (
  <div>Fancy loading container!</div>
)

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: ("AIzaSyBHq-A0EL3usDeqH5q8B635Rafxcguc0a8"),
  LoadingContainer: LoadingContainer
})(MapContainer)
```

Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: Did you forget to add key?

Comment: You can try to first assign a variable such as: 
const markers = this.objMarkers.map((marker) => 
                    <Marker title={marker.title} name={marker.name} />
                );

and then you can use markers variable inside Map tags like that: {markers}

Take a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/yk5vprz1nz
Also, you don't need to use return keyword, map function already returns a new array.

Comment: `this.objMarkers = [` instead of `const objMarkers = [`. and plus replies below

Comment: the same for `style`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) in the react docs for a detailed explanation of how to render lists in `jsx`.

Your `return` is misplaced. You can't use it like this in `jsx`. The correct syntax for inline mapping an array is:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Map 
            google={this.props.google}
            style={this.style}
            initialCenter={{lat: 35.85472104, lng: 14.48779873}}
            zoom={11}
        >
            {this.objMarkers.map((marker) => (
                <Marker key={marker.name} title={marker.title} name={marker.name} />
             ))}
        </Map>
    );
}
```

Also note that if you create siblings of the same type [you need to assign a unique `key` prop to each of them](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Also in your `constructor` you created local variables. They only exist inside your `constructor`. You need to assign the values to instance properties as @Evgeny Timoshenko correctly pointed out or they will not be accessible with `this` in your `render()` function:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.style = {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    }

    this.objMarkers = [
        {
            title: "The marker`s title will appear as a tooltip.",
            name: "Soma",
            position: [35.85472104, "14.48779873"]
        },
        {
            title: "The marker`s title will appear as a tooltip.",
            name: "Soma",
                position: ["35.9220325", "14.37038234"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much all of you. Works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
{markers.map.
```

Instead of return.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Key in returning set of Marker component, And remember that you are in **JSX** so use **curly braces** to return the element..

```
{ this.objMarkers.map((marker, index) => 
       <Marker key={index} title={marker.title} name={marker.name} />
    )
}
```

[Here is the Complete reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)